# SUMIFS on Filtered Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a `SUMIFS` in an Excel sheet where I need to take into consideration cells that are filtered. I can accomplish this with a pivot table, but the same source data is already being using in a handful of Bubble Charts which update on filtering anyways. The only reason for this other table to the data needs to be aggregated differently to get the desired chart out. I am trying to avoid Pivots so that once the user selects their filters in the Source Table (using Slicers) the destination table and accompanying chart just update. If I use a pivot table to handle this part the user will have to duplicate work by putting their parameters into the Slicers and the PivotTable.

`Row#` in the real data is a unique identifier for each row. For filtering there is roughly 20 columns that could be filtered.

I have seen that `SUMPRODUCT` can do this, but I cannot wrap my head around how to do it with my data set.

**Source Table Example**

```
+------+---------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+----------+
| Row# |    Amount     | Class |Channel| Other | Columns | ToFilter |
+------+---------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+----------+
|    1 |  $122,616.16  |    10 | A     | Stuff | Stuff   | Stuff    |
|    2 |  $128,587.43  |     1 | B     | Stuff | Stuff   | Stuff    |
|    3 |  $273,055.04  |    10 | C     | Stuff | Stuff   | Stuff    |
|   25 |  $144,087.59  |     4 | A     | Stuff | Stuff   | Stuff    |
|   26 |  $273,537.45  |     2 | A     | Stuff | Stuff   | Stuff    |
|   27 |  $110,177.94  |     2 | B     | Stuff | Stuff   | Stuff    |
| 3674 |  $455,133.20  |     2 | C     | Stuff | Stuff   | Stuff    |
+------+---------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+----------+
```

**Destination Table Example**

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+---------------+-----+---------------+
| Channel |       1       |       2       |   3    |       4       |  ~  |      10       |
+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+---------------+-----+---------------+
| A       |  $-           |  $273,537.45  |  $-    |  $144,087.59  |  ~  |  $122,616.16  |
| B       |  $128,587.43  |  $110,177.94  |  $-    |  $-           |  ~  |  $-           |
| C       |  $-           |  $455,133.20  |  $-    |  $-           |  ~  |  $273,055.04  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+---------------+-----+---------------+
```

Comment: I don't see how you get the destination table from the source table.  What determines the "Channel"?

Comment: If the user can select slicers in the source table, why do you think they can't do the same with a pivot table? If you can accomplish the desired result with a pivot table, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the source table is located at A1:G8, and the destination table is located at A10:K13 .

Put '=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$8,MATCH(1,INDEX((B$10=$D$2:$D$8)*($A11=$E$2:$E$8),0,1),0)),"-")` in B11 and drag till the end.

Idea : use multiple criteria index match & wrap it in iferror(). $ is used to lock the reference column/row.

Ref : https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Please share if it works/not. ( :